# Observables not resetting to initial state after route change?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, reactive-programming

I have an observable of data stream bound to a grid datasource as follow, When an item is selected the grid data populates, but when i navigate to other route of the application and navigate back to the same route i can see that the variables i am using are getting redeclared and reinitialized but the observables are not since they use combineLatest, i think the grid will always be bound to the latest item emitted from the source observable. Is there a way i can reset this observable to initial state during route change without calling the next() method of the Subject.

```
selectedMasterPlan$ = combineLatest([this.masterPlans$, this.commissionPlanService.masterPlanChange$]).pipe(
map(([plans, id]) => {
  const plan = plans.filter(x => x.masterPlanId === id);
  if (plan.length > 0) {
    return plan[0];
  }
  return null;
}));
```

1) **The this.commissionPlanService.masterPlanChange$ change is an action stream observable bound to user selection in template.**

2) **The this.masterPlans$ is a data stream observable.**

I think moving these declaration to ngOnInit will help, but I dont want to use ngOnInit.

Comment: you have to subscribe to it `.pipe(....).subscribe( result => console.log(result));`

Comment: are you subscribing in your template?

Comment: also, without seeing what your action and data streams i can't really help. Are you using shareReplay(1) or saving the data in localStorage?